# Writing complex queries using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Please How can i write this same query in Laravel, I am a bit confused.

```
SELECT e.employee_id
     , e.english_name
     , e.reports_to
     , d.department
     , p.position_name
     , a.CHECK_IN_TIME
     , a.CHECK_OUT_TIME 
  FROM as_tbl_employee_master e 
  join as_tbl_department d 
    on e.department_id = d.id 
  join as_tbl_employee_position p
    on e.position_id = p.id 
  join as_tbl_emp_attendance_daily_log a
    on att.EMPLOYEE_ID = e.employee_id
 where e.reports_to = 18
```

Comment: Help us out here and explain it a bit better. What models do you have?

Comment: DB::table('as_tbl_employee_master AS emp')
          ->select('emp.id','emp.employee_id', 'emp.sys_emp_id','emp.english_name','dept.department','pos.position_name','att.CHECK_IN_TIME','att.CHECK_OUT_TIME')
          ->join('as_tbl_department AS dept','emp.department_id','=', 'dept.id')
          ->join('as_tbl_employee_position AS pos', 'emp.position_id', '=', 'pos.id')
          ->join('as_tbl_emp_attendance_daily_log AS att', 'att.EMPLOYEE_ID', '=', 'emp.employee_id')
          ->where('emp.employee_id', $sys_emp_id)
          ->orderby('att.CHECK_IN_TIME', 'DESC')
          ->get();

Comment: @tadman, I wrote the above query using one select, but i now want to select from the result based on a specific field, I dont know how to go about it, Thanks

Comment: your inner query has no aggregation, it could just exist at the top level and have the `WHERE .. = 18` appended to it.

Comment: It's much better to include code in an edit to the question. It's not formatted as nicely in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below query which is written in laravel-

```
DB::table('as_tbl_employee_master AS emp') ->select('emp.id','emp.employee_id',
'emp.sys_emp_id','emp.english_name','dept.department','pos.position_name',
'att.CHECK_IN_TIME','att.CHECK_OUT_TIME') 
->join('as_tbl_department AS dept','emp.department_id','=', 'dept.id') 
->join('as_tbl_employee_position AS pos', 'emp.position_id', '=', 'pos.id') 
->join('as_tbl_emp_attendance_daily_log AS att', 'att.EMPLOYEE_ID', '=', 'emp.employee_id') 
->where('emp.employee_id', $sys_emp_id) 
->orderby('att.CHECK_IN_TIME', 'DESC') 
->get();
```

Or

Alternative is using same query which you have written but with `DB` helper like -

Add `use DB;` in your controller.

```
DB::select('select * from 
(SELECT emp.employee_id,emp.english_name, emp.reports_to, 
dept.department, pos.position_name, 
att.CHECK_IN_TIME,att.CHECK_OUT_TIME 
FROM as_tbl_employee_master emp 
inner join as_tbl_department dept on emp.department_id = dept.id 
inner join as_tbl_employee_position pos on emp.position_id = pos.id 
inner join as_tbl_emp_attendance_daily_log att on att.EMPLOYEE_ID = emp.employee_id) as TAB 
where TAB.reports_to = 18');
```

Also, using sql injection is a better practice.

```
DB::select('select * from 
(SELECT emp.employee_id,emp.english_name, emp.reports_to, 
dept.department, pos.position_name, 
att.CHECK_IN_TIME,att.CHECK_OUT_TIME 
FROM as_tbl_employee_master emp 
inner join as_tbl_department dept on emp.department_id = dept.id 
inner join as_tbl_employee_position pos on emp.position_id = pos.id 
inner join as_tbl_emp_attendance_daily_log att on att.EMPLOYEE_ID = emp.employee_id) as TAB 
where TAB.reports_to = ?', [18]);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Careful, that's not Eloquent. Soon as you tap into `join()` you're talking to Query\Builder via a Magic __call(), meaning you won't get the benefit of Model configurations from that point.

Comment: @Saurabh Guple, Thanks, It helped me, got it working